# React-elastic-carousel works, but vscode shows error warning

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, web-frontend, react-elastic-carousel

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHRgM.png)

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy0Ev.png)

I'm learning to use typescript so I don't understand what's wrong.
Despite the error warning, the application continues to work, and the carousel component works despite the error...

Comment: Like jerryrighteverything would say, VSC is VSC and VSC breaks.

Comment: I managed to solve it by passing all the props to the component with the spread operator, passing a const object with the necessary parameters